# Can the value obtained by dijit.byId('').value be compared to a String?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am relatively new to **Spring MVC** and **Dojo/Dijit** widgets and I am stuck with a problem. I need to unblock a particular div based on the option selected from the dropdown i.e. when the user selects the reason as "Unexperienced" I am supposed to unblock a `div` with `id = "unexpUser" style="display:none;"` to collect some additional information.

JSP -

```
<select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" name="userReason" id = "reason">
    <option value="opt0">Experienced</option>
    <option value="opt1">Not experienced</option>
</select>
```

JC -

```
<script>
if(dijit.byId('reason').value == "opt1"){
    unexpUser.style.display = 'block';  
    }
</script>
```

When the page loads, the option displayed on the dropdown is "Experienced". When I change the option to "Not experienced" , I need to unblock the div but this particular code doesn't seem to be the right code for comparing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`.value` is not the right way to get value from a `dijit widget` instead use:

```
dijit.byId('reason').get("value")
```

Comment: The div still does not show.  The div with id = "unexpUser" style="display:none;" is inside another div with id = "firstPage" style="display:bold;" . Do you think this might be contributing to the fact that on comparison the I do not get the div with id = "unexpUser" to unblock?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to use dom-styles.set to change the css style of the div

Answer (score 0):

Use onchange listener :

```
dijit.byId('reason').on("change",function(evt){
    alert(evt); //(evt == value of option )
    // your code here  
});
```

Comment: Yes. I did just that. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

okay I got my mistake. This is the solution. @Harpreet Singh your solution works perfectly with this code.
JSP-

```
<form:select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" path "" name="userReason" id = "reason" onchange="myFunction1();">
                                            <option value="opt0">Experienced</option>
                                            <option value="opt1">Not experienced</option>

                                    </form:select>
```

and in my JS I created a function for the String comparison.
JS -

```
<script>
function myFunction1(){
if(dijit.byId('reason').get("value") == "opt1"){

     unexpUser.style.display = 'block'; 

    }
</script>
```

this works. Thank you so much for your help!